# Discrete Math Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

How many $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $3\cdot10^{13}<x<10^{14}$?

and one of the numbers 1, 2,. . . , 9 exactly once and no zeros next to each other?

I think to on orderings without repetition but it is hard to understand $3\cdot10^{13}<x<10^{14}$ is bugging me what do they mean?

Comment: It means $3\underbrace{0000000000000}_{13\text{ zeros}}<x<1\underbrace{00000000000000}_{14\text{ zeros}}$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $ x $ can take $ 10^{14}- 3×10^{13} -1 =7×10^{13}-1 $ values. $ x $ thus has 14 digits. Take the digits of $ x $ as $$ ABABABABABABAB $$ where A represents the places reserved for non-zero digits and B represents places where zeroes are allowed along with non-zero digits. There are 7 $ A's $ so out of the 9 digits, for the first digit we have 6 choices and as the order is important for the other digits we have 8P6 choices for the remaining 6 $ A's $. Now for the $ B's $. We still have 2 remaining digits. We can choose any 2 digits in $\binom {9}{2} $ and so we can place these digits in $\binom {7}{2} $. So, the total number of ways or number of numbers that $ x $ can take is = 6× 8P6 × $\binom {9}{2} $ × $\binom {7}{2} $. Hope it helps.